# How to consolidate partitions while retaining data on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, partitioning, backup, file-management

So I have what seems like a somewhat basic question, but it seems the answer might not be so simple. I have done many googling prior to posting here and i am just not getting what i want.

Here's my situation:

I have a Mac Mini with 2 HDD Hard drives, both of which have multiple partitions with separate installed bootable Mac OS on them. My mac is not that great and eventually for some reason it would just go painfully slow, have indefinite beach balls, and errors. I would have to restart all the time, and so as to not deal with re-installing the OS and trying to keep all my files, I just did some research and found I could partition and create an entirely new boot up operating system on them. It would be good at the start then eventually crap out, so i just kept making partitions to use a fresh OS. Some of my old partitions are so bad, I can't even load finder on boot (just black screen). I did not intend to use these partition OS as my new workstations, but it eventually just became that way. I would end up installing and using the same programs (like Photoshop, FL Studio, Firefox, Chrome etc.) like my original OS workstation, and creating files/projects within these apps. On top of that I have been running very low on space and always find myself slowly moving files across partitions just to free up a few gigs on the one I'm using. I always get confused at what partition has what files/data on it. I have had enough of this ridiculous setup! I just want all my files, in ONE place, on ONE account, and all files of the same program to be in the same program on ONE app! All on a clean fresh install of Mac OS. I don't even know where to begin.

The only idea I had was making Time Machine backups of each partition, creating one last partition with a fresh install, and then adding each backup from each partition with migration assistant hoping it all consolidates into one. If Migration assistant even works that way (I never used it). Then after that, delete all the old partitions. The problem here is I don't know how things will work for the apps. Does it backup my app data and the files/projects i had in these programs? What about FL Studio or Photoshop projects on each individual system? Will it combine/consolidate these into one folder and then be able to be view and opened with no problems on the new machine? If when I migrate one backup, will another overwrite anything at all instead of keep EVERYTHING from both machines?

Since I'm almost out of space I have bought a 2TB External hard drive that I can save the Time Machine backups on. The OS I'm on right now has been the most recent partition and is now starting to be unreasonably slow for literally everything. I'm in need of another fresh install or something but don't have anymore room for another partition and if I create another my mind is going to explode as I'm kind of OCD about this type of stuff.

My system storage setup:

[image: storage]

Comment: Welcome to Super User Zach! I have edited your post to remove the opinion request (which would be [off-topic](/help/off-topic) here). However, I think it could possibly  use some further trimming; I wasn't sure where to draw the line as some of the info in the 'story' -- stories tend to be less well-received here than technical descriptions -- is german to the situation you find yourself in. Please feel free to [edit your post further](https://superuser.com/posts/1313033/edit) if you feel you can focus it down more.

Comment: That aside, given the level of general dispersion of files, my gut says that it's unlikely an automated process will be able to 'automagically' figure out which files are wanted on the new partition- it may feel to you to sort that out.

Comment: Thirdly, given *"I just did some research and found I could partition and create an entirely new boot up operating system on them. It would be good at the start then eventually crap out*", it may be worth figuring out the root cause of that issue -- an OS shouldn't in theory  'just lose' a bootloader! -- as what's to stop that happening when you create this last one partition *to rule them all and bind them*?

Comment: I think that you should install the OS and the applications on an SSD drive. In my opinion this is the only way to make your Mac faster